# Based on a condition in one column set a condition in another column

Tags: r

If the values in df$nr is under 5, I want it to say A in the column next to it. If it is exactly 5 it should say B and if it is above 5 it should say C. I have tried the code below but cant make it work. Suggestions?

```
set.seed(1)
nr <- sample(10,10)
dat <- rep(1,10)
df <- data.frame(nr,dat)
df

ifelse(df$nr<=5,df$dat[df$dat=="A"],1)

for(i in df$nr) if(i %in% <5) df$dat <- "A"
for(i in df$nr) if(i %in% ==5) df$dat <- "B"
for(i in df$nr) if(i %in% >5) df$dat <- "C"
```

Comment: `with(df, ifelse(nr == 5, 'B', ifelse(nr < 5, 'A', 'C')))`

Comment: @Ronak Shah thanks! I have one question, I read it as if nr < 5, set "A" and "C". How does it know that the data over 5 should be C?

Comment: It does not. Anything which is not 5 or not less than 5 is 'C'.

Comment: @Ronak Shah ahh of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option, using the `tidyverse`, longer than the answer by Allan, but imo easier to understand:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>%
      mutate( dat = case_when( nr < 5 ~ "A",
                               nr == 5 ~ "B",
                               nr > 5 ~ "C"))
```

Do note that, as per Allans comment, the tidyverse is a large dependency. Using it for this single task might be overkill, in that case you would rather use one of the other suggested solutions.

Comment: I think you're right - it probably is easier to understand, but to achieve this you have solved a simple indexing problem by loading megabytes of dependencies and using unnecessary branching logic. I'm not sure that this pays for the little extra effort

Comment: absolutely, for this single task it's way too much. I'm surprised it was accepted, just wanted to leave the option out there in case some future reader is already using the tidyverse.

Answer (score 1):

This is a one-liner in base R. The `sign` function returns -1 for any negative value, 0 for 0 and 1 for a positive number. So `nr - 5` will give -1 for anything under 5, 0 for 5, and 1 for anything over 5. If we add 2 to this, it will give us the numbers 1, 2, 3 in place of -1, 0, 1. We can use 1, 2, 3 as the indices of `LETTERS` to get the appropriate "A", "B" or "C":

```r
within(df, dat <- LETTERS[sign(nr - 5) + 2])
#> #>    nr dat
#> #> 1   9   C
#> #> 2   4   A
#> #> 3   7   C
#> #> 4   1   A
#> #> 5   2   A
#> #> 6   5   B
#> #> 7   3   A
#> #> 8  10   C
#> #> 9   6   C
#> #> 10  8   C
```